# Reverse ordering dplyr's group_ by()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm writing a print method for a package that I'm working on. It's basic task is to display a set of tasks grouped by date. Because working on a console implies that the last thing printed is closest to the prompt, I want the oldest date to be listed last. Without all the hassle of the print method and dispatching, the core code is something along this:

```
d <- data.frame(thr = as.Date(Sys.time()) + seq(-3,3,1),
                tsk = paste0('t', 1:7), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d %>% group_by(thr) %>% 
  do(x = {
      thr <- format(.$thr, '%d-%m-%Y')
      cat(thr, '\n', .$tsk, '\n') 
     })
```

This generates

```
02-09-2015 
 t1 
03-09-2015 
 t2 
04-09-2015 
 t3 
05-09-2015 
 t4 
06-09-2015 
 t5 
07-09-2015 
 t6 
08-09-2015 
 t7
```

But I'd like to order it in reverse chronological order so that the oldest date is printed last:

```
08-09-2015
 t7
07-09-2015
 t6 
...
```

In normal (non printing code) this would be easy using arrange(-thr) but I haven't figured out a way to do this in the print function.

Comment: `cat` is called per group here so it is not "aware" that other groups even exist. So either don't do it by group or set the grouping order apriori (like you already suggested). Also, calling `format` per group is kind of inefficient and I would suggest doing it before the per group operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer with NA's moved to the top.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data.frame(thr = 
             as.Date(Sys.time()) + c(seq(-3,3,1), seq(-3,3,1)) %>%
             c(NA),
           tsk = paste0('t', 1:15)) %>%
  arrange(tsk) %>%
  group_by(thr) %>%
  summarize(
    tsk_out = 
      paste(
        thr %>% first %>% format('%d-%m-%Y'),
        '\n',
        tsk %>% unique %>% paste(collapse = " "),
        '\n') ) %>%
  arrange(thr %>% order(na.last = FALSE, decreasing = TRUE)) %>% 
  use_series(tsk_out) %>%
  cat
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

data.frame(thr = as.Date(Sys.time()) + c(seq(-3,3,1), seq(-3,3,1)),
           tsk = paste0('t', c(1:14)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  arrange(tsk) %>%
  group_by(thr) %>%
  summarize(
    tsk_out = 
      paste(
        thr %>% first %>% format('%d-%m-%Y'),
        '\n',
        tsk %>% unique %>% paste(collapse = " "),
        '\n') ) %>%
  arrange(desc(thr)) %>%
  use_series(tsk_out) %>%
  cat
```

Comment: OP said that they already know how to solve this using `arrange`. How does comntless code dump help in any way?

Comment: It seemed like OP said that they didn't know how to use arrange in combination with printing.

Comment: Indeed @bramtayl, I was struggling to implement the sort in dplyr idiom. 

But, wooah, that introduces a few new functions I never heard of; especially the coding inside the `paste()` is cool! Great suggestion if only for that reason; but it also solves my conundrum. Took me quite a bit of time to figure step by step what was happening.

Comment: @bramtayl Another thing that I didn't pose in the OP: how would you handle the case when `thr` is `NA` and I want the `NA`'s on top (i.e., cat first)??